# При использовании для консоли termios не дает удалить символы

Tags: c++, linux

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь найти ошибку или недочет в реализации ввода скрытых символов в консоли линукса. Делается это для поля пароль.
Но например если я что то введу, а потом передумал и пытаюсь ввести что то другое, удалить символы не получается. Они остаются.
Может кто знает почему так происходит?

```
struct termios oldt, newt;
tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);

    std::string answer = question(question);

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    return answer;
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, что именноты подразумеваешь под `«Но например если я что то введу, а потом передумал и пытаюсь ввести что то другое, удалить символы не получается. Они остаются. Может кто знает почему так происходит?»`... предлогаю составить полноценный [mcve], а также ввод к нему и ожидаемый/получаемый вывод...

Comment: А не проще ли использовать libreadline, где всё уже есть (Даже комбинация по умолчанию для сброса введённого [неверно] пароля).